# How to Access and Control a Document Scanner[ADF Front and Back] like Kodak or Hp from Python and Django

Tags: django, python-3.6

I already tried Pyinsane2 to access the scanner. It communicate with Kodak scanner but it Scan only first page as clear and remaining pages are fully blur.
and also pyinsane2 is no more maintainable. and also i don't know how to use Libinsane which is successor of  Pyinsane2.
I need a help to control and scan from Python Django.

```
def scan_process(request):
    pyinsane2.init()
    try:
        devices = pyinsane2.get_devices()
        assert (len(devices) > 0)
        device = devices[0]
        print("I'm going to use the following scanner: %s" % (str(device)))
        try:
            pyinsane2.set_scanner_opt(device, "source", "ADF Front")
            # pyinsane2.set_scanner_opt(device, 'duplex', ['both'])
        except PyinsaneException:
            print("No document feeder found")
        pyinsane2.set_scanner_opt(device, 'mode', ['Color'])

        pyinsane2.maximize_scan_area(device)
        source = 'Auto'
        if (device.options['source'].constraint_type
                == pyinsane.SaneConstraintType.STRING_LIST):
            if 'Auto' in device.options['source'].constraint:
                source = 'Auto'
            elif 'FlatBed' in device.options['source'].constraint:
                source = 'FlatBed'
        else:
            print("Warning: Unknown constraint type on the source: %d"% device.options['source'].constraint_type)
        res = 200
        colour = 'Color'
        # set_scanner_opt(device, 'resolution', res)
        # set_scanner_opt(device, 'source', source)
        # set_scanner_opt(device, 'mode', colour)
        set_scanner_opt(device,'quality','maximum')
        # set_scanner_opt(device,'duplex','both')
        #
        pyinsane2.maximize_scan_area(device)
        scan_session = device.scan(multiple=True)

        try:
            while True:
                try:
                    scan_session.scan.read()
                except EOFError:
                    print("Got a page ! (current number of pages read: %d)" % (len(scan_session.images)))
        except StopIteration:
            print("Document feeder is now empty. Got %d pages" % len(scan_session.images))
        for idx in range(0, len(scan_session.images)):
            image = scan_session.images[idx]

            file_name = 'Scan_'
            file_extension = '.pdf' #.bmp
            file_name_new = file_name + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S"))
            lsfile_name = str((BASE_DIR + '/Bigflow_Demojs/media/' + file_name_new + file_extension))

            lsfile_name_db  = str(('/media/' + file_name_new + file_extension))

            path = Path(lsfile_name)
            path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

            image.save(lsfile_name)   #### Save the Scanned Data

            # from io import BytesIO   ##### Detect The Barcode Data
            # buffered = BytesIO()
            # image.save(buffered, format="JPEG")
            # img_str = base64.b64encode(buffered.getvalue())
            # test = img_str
            #
            # obj_code = base64code.bar_qrcode()
            # obj_code.base64_data = img_str
            # ldict_data = obj_code.read_base64()
            #
            # barcode_data = ldict_data
            # img_path_db = lsfile_name_db
            #
            # out_data = {}
            # out_data = {"MESSAGE":"FOUND","DATA":ldict_data,"IMAGE_PATH":lsfile_name_db}

            # image.save("GRT_%d.bmp" % idx)
            # return JsonResponse(out_data,safe=False)


    except Exception as e:
        str(e)
    # finally:
        # pyinsane2.exit()
```

It need to scan all pages both front and back.